# List item location not updating on scroll

Tags: c#, listview

I can't seem to find a matching response to this, but I am trying to test my interface and it works flawlessly so far except that when I implement the scroll wheel. The draggable label automatically attaches itself to the location of a list item when it is selected. When the scroll wheel moves, the attached label moves with it. However, there is a delay in the selected item coordinates updating for the attached label to use. I tried other events that could trigger the immediate position like a button would, but to no avail. Might anyone have an idea as a work around?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace matchMoving
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Label_Mouse_Down);
            label1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Label_Mouse_Move);
            listBox1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Scroll);
            listBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Move);
            listBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Down);
        }

        Rectangle IndexLocation;
        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        public void List_Function()
            {
                label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                IndexLocation = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                int nx = Convert.ToInt32(IndexLocation.X);
                int ny = Convert.ToInt32(IndexLocation.Y);
                label1.Location = new Point(nx, ny);
                textBox1.Text = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString();
            }

        public void List_Mouse_Move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                List_Function();
            }
        }

        public void List_Mouse_Scroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                List_Function();
        }

        private void List_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                List_Function();
            }
        }

        private void Label_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        private void Label_Mouse_Move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point start = Point.Empty;
                int nx = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X + (e.X - start.X), 0), label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width);
                int ny = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y + (e.Y - start.Y), 0), label1.Parent.Height - label1.Height);
                label1.Location = new Point(nx, ny);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("This is new text");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found out what will work. This code will create a label that displays the index of each listbox item. This label is draggable. When a listbox item is selected, the label will attach to the location of the listbox item. The label follows the location of the listbox item when the scrollwheel is scrolled or when the mouse selects a new listbox item. To implement a click controllable scroll probably would have to be custom?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MouseMatchMoving
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // These are the event handling functions
            label1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Label_Mouse_Down);
            label1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Label_Mouse_Move);
            label1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Label_Mouse_Up);
            listBox1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Scroll);
            listBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Move);
            listBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(List_Mouse_Down);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BProgress);
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BDowork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BWCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            // Start the backgroundworker
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            label1.BringToFront();
        }

        Rectangle IndexLocation;
        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        // Form loading
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("This is new text");
            }
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        // This backgroundworker invokes the GUI thread
        private void BDowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => List_Function()));
                return;
            }
        }

        private void BProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.UserState);
        }

        private void BWCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Cancelled);
        }

        // This begins the mouse ListBox Focus functions
        private void List_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                List_Function();
            }
        }

        public void List_Mouse_Move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                List_Function();
            }
        }

        // This is the mouse scrolling function which calls the backgroundworker
        public void List_Mouse_Scroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
            listBox1.GetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        // This is invokes the draggable label mouse functions
        private void Label_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }

        private void Label_Mouse_Move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point start = Point.Empty;
                int nx = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X + (e.X - start.X), 0), label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width);
                int ny = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y + (e.Y - start.Y), 0), label1.Parent.Height - label1.Height);
                label1.Location = new Point(nx, ny);
            }
        }

        private void Label_Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }

        // This is the mouse list tracking function
        public void List_Function()
        {
            label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            IndexLocation = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            int nx = Convert.ToInt32(IndexLocation.X);
            int ny = Convert.ToInt32(IndexLocation.Y);
            label1.Location = new Point(nx, ny);
            textBox1.Text = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(listBox1.GetItemRectangle(listBox1.SelectedIndex));
        }
    }
}
```